# jQuery Ajax call to database on click ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Let's say I've got a table in a SQL Server database that looks like

```
StateName  notes
alabama    'notes about alabama'
alaska     'notes about alaska'
.....      .........
```

EDIT: This question will be divided into two parts, one for the initial problem and why it didn't work and my reformed, hopefully more accurate second solution.

In the web form, the name of the state are represented as link button inside of a table.  I'm trying to use jQuery to make an Ajax database call when a user clicks on a state name, the text value of the link button will be send to a stored procedure in the database. 
That stored procedure is something like

```
create proc spGetStateData
@stateName varchar(50)
as
begin
select notes from 
states
where statename = @stateName
end
```

For testing purposes, I added a a text box and a button so that when the user types the name of the state into the text box, the `Notes` column from the `States` database table is displayed.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetStateData(string stateName)
        {
            string stateNotes = string.Empty;
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStateData", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateName", stateName);
                    stateNotes = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
            }
            return stateNotes;
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStateNotes.Text = GetStateData(txtStateName.Text);
            hiddenDiv.Visible = true;
        }
```

This part works, so I know it's not my WebMethod or a database connection that's failing.  When I try to do this same thing with jQuery, it fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#states a").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetStateData",
                    data: $(this).text(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (x) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Okay, I pulled open developer tools for Chrome and found out what the reason for the AJAX failing was that I was getting a 'couldn't load resource HTTP 500 error'.  It was telling me that the method name and parameter couldn't be found (even though by all rights they were there).  So then I tried a second way, which seems like a better way (if I can get it to work!)

So then I thought 'let's use a WebService'. And here is my rendition of that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                var stateName = JSON.stringify({ "stateName": $(this).text() });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GetStateData.asmx/GetData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: stateName,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#lblNotes").text(data);
                    },
                    error: function (x) {
                        alert('message');
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a href="#">Alabama</a>
    <a href="#">Alaska</a>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNotes"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace jQueryAjaxWebservice
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]    
    public  class GetStateData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public string GetData(string stateName)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            string stateNotes ="test" ;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStateData",con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateName", stateName);
                    stateNotes = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }

            }
           return stateNotes;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested the WebService, and it works.  However, when I try to call the web service code from default.aspx, I get `[Object object]` as the `lblNotes` text.  If I change (data) to "test" then I get the correct output of "test" to the screen.  So the faulty part is in the `success` portion of the Ajax call. I put a breakpoint on the GetData function and `stateNotes` is receiving the proper text value, so the only place left for the problem to be is in the `success` line of the ajax call.

Comment: change your data to data: "{'stateName' : '" + $(this).text() + "'}",

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your return statement, make sure the code is reaching that line and has the value expected.

Comment: @Jay yeah, it's reading from the database and getting the correct value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the way you format your `data` option in `ajax` might be wrong. It always works in key-value pairs. In the current form you are only sending the value, no key. You might have to change it to this format :

```
var stateName = { "stateName" : $(this).text()}
```

or

```
var stateName = JSON.stringify({ "stateName" : $(this).text()})
```

But mostly, I've seen only the second one to work, partly because jQuery doesn't *pre-process* the `data` option for it be readable in C#. So it's always recommended to use `stringify` on `ajax` requests with `type` set to `"POST"`.

Then, in your `ajax` call,

```
$.ajax({
   //ajax options
   data : stateName
   //some more ajax options
});
```

Also, you might want to make your `error` option more descriptive, like this :

```
 $.ajax({
       //ajax options
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
       }
 });
```

This will tell you where you're going wrong and you could debug it as well.

**EDIT:**

In the `success` function, try looking for `data.d` instead of `data`. You'll find that your data lies inside it. Also, as mentioned before (***and i cant stress this enough***), please use `error` handler with `xhr` options. It'll be easier to debug then. [Read this if you want to know why the result returns `data.d` and not just `data`.](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/#comment-34045)

```
$.ajax({
   //some ajax options
   success: function (data) {
        //data.d will contain your data
        console.log(data.d);
        $("#lblNotes").text(data.d);
   },
   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         console.log(xhr);
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was the part that I wasn't too sure about.  Let me test this and see what she says.

Comment: yeah, I thought your solution was what I needed but I've ran into some more trouble and I should've been more thorough in my testing before accepting.  I'm still futzing around with things trying to get it to work and barring a miracle I'll be updating my question to reflect my new problems.  Your diligence is appreciated! :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie what do you get when you make a `console.log(data)` inside success?

Comment: Finally got it working with your edits!  I swear I (thought) I did the same exact thing a dozen times but now it's finally working