# Insert Master Detail in MVC5

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an Inventory Control System in MVC5 i need help, how to insert/update master and detail data on one click?

Like below openERP picture

[image]

Comment: You might need to write an OnInsert StoredProcedure to implement cascading updates.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am not familiar with StoredProcedure have you any example link to do this in mvc. some body advise me to insert using jQuery. is it good and secure to do this using jQuery?

Comment: It's up to you whether yo do it server-side (C#) or client-side (jQuery, with AJAX). For the latter, see the following as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929665/jquery-ajax-call-to-database-on-click-asp-net. If you do it in C#, you should be able to set up the table into which you are going to insert to automatically update the other table, something like:
REFERENCES ChildTable (xyz) ON INSERT CASCADE.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be done with json-jquery

```
var data=[{customerid:101,customername:'name',
detaile:[
{customerid:101,productid:1,product:'service1',desc:'any...',quantity:1,subtotal:100},
{customerid:101,productid:2,product:'service2',desc:'note ',quantity:2,subtotal:200}
        ]
    }];

ajax request :
        $.ajax({
            url:'/urlcontroller/addDetail',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
alert('success');
            }
            , error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert('error');
            }
        });
```

and parameters in Action shoud be a class like:

```
public class customer
{
    public int customerid { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public customerdetail[] detaile { get; set; }
}

public class customerdetail
{
    public int customerid { get; set; }
    public int productid { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int subtotal { get; set; }
}
```

action result:

```
public jsonresult addDetail(customer records)
{
    var db = new StorageContext();
    db.customer.Add(records);
    db.SaveChanges();
    foreach (var item in records.detaile)
    {
        db.customerdetail.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```